# Logic to calculate the number of the day of year which is not a holiday?

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle

What I Require :- To a DB table which has entry of all the days of an year with a flag "IsHoliday" with "Yes" if its a holiday and "No" if it is not.

I want to give index to the day which is not a holiday starting from 1 to the first workingday of the year and so on with the help of a batch.

Current situation :- is that There is a holiday table maintained by manual entries in my DB(Oracle). Whenever we have to check for a particular date for a day to be working or holiday we hit the DB for each date entered and compare with holiday table which is an expensive way.

What I Require seems an optimised way therefore i want to maintain a DB table which has WorkingDays as entries with the day of the year along with it as in some business scenarios I have to give number of the day as return(if 4th jan(thursday) is 4th working day then I want to return 4, 8th jan as 6)

CAL_DT  IS_HOLIDAY  WKNG_DAY_INDX

1-Jan-11    Yes

2-Jan-11    No  1

3-Jan-11    No  2

4-Jan-11    Yes

5-Jan-11    No  3

6-Jan-11    No  4

The Index gets populated by a batch checking the is_holiday=no field is my requirement.

I hope I am clear now??

I would appreciate the suggestions.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague: what is your _input_ here? Does your table already contain the entries for each day with the _isHoliday_ flag set appropriately? Or you want to manually populate your table like that? Moreover, what _year_ are we talking about: there are holidays in some cultures that are held on a day relative to some important _event_, so please define what kind of holidays are you talking about. Also, what is a _batch_ and what does _all_ have to do with _Java_? I humbly suggest you to include your table definition in your question and try to refine it a bit.

Comment: Jeez, this is one confused question!! What is it you are asking here? How do your tables look? Which DB are you using? What are you aiming to achieve? Please enlighten us!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ROW_NUMBER() analytic function to produce a sequential number.

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CalendarDate) AS RowNum_
     , CalendarDate
FROM MyDB.Calendar
Where IsHoliday = 'No';
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have two big problems here:

1 - Not all cultures have the same holidays, so your entries for India will not be the same as for the US will not be for most other countries.

2 - a lot of holidays move around, so a (day of year, isHoliday) tuple cannot handle, say, the 4th Thursday of November as a holiday because it is not the same day of year. Not to mention leap years will mess up holidays after February.

What you should probably do is have several columns in a holiday table - a set of columns for moving holidays and a set of columns where the holiday is always the same day of the month. The columns for one will be null when the columns for the other are populated. Good luck with the SQL to translate those into day-of-year though.

Comment: My concept is going to work for banks. Consider it that holiday list will be updated manually every year and rest of the days(working days) needs to be indexed.

Comment: CAL_DT IS_HOLIDAY WKNG_DAY_INDX
1-Jan-11 Yes 
2-Jan-11 No 1
3-Jan-11 No 2
4-Jan-11 Yes 
5-Jan-11 No 3
6-Jan-11 No 4
  
this is the kind of structure I want to make of a data base where Working_index gets populated by a batch checking for the is_holiday=No

Comment: I don't think this is so much of a database question as a programming question. You're just storing dates, and a yes/no, and date_of_year. How you generate those is probably better solved programmatically. Just write a loop that goes through the days of the year, checks that it is not a weekend or holiday, and keeps a counter of how many workdays there have been.